# Referencing variable name from list when using prop.table in a loop

Tags: r

I am trying to quickly generate several `ggplot2` graphs from contingency tables using a `for` loop in R.  Each variable (`R1...R7`) is segmented by a single variable (`segment_r`).

I wrote the following loop, but keep getting errors.

```
question_names<-paste("R",1:7,sep='') # Create list with question names

attach(df)
for (i in length(question_names)) {
  question_names[i]<-factor(question_names[i])
  means<-prop.table(table(get(question_names[i]),segment_r),2)*100
  means.long<-melt(means,id.vars="segment_r")
  p<-ggplot(means.long,aes(x=Var1,y=value,fill=factor(Var2)))+
    geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")+coord_flip()+
    scale_fill_discrete(name="Segment",
                        breaks=c(1:4),
                        labels=c(1:4))+
    xlab("")+ylab("Mean Percentage")
  p <- p + facet_wrap( ~ Var2, ncol=4)
  p
  }
detach(df)
```

I've tried to include `get` in `table`, which yields the error: `Error in get(question_names[i]) : object '1' not found`).  However, omitting `get` also doesn't work: `Error in table(question_names[i], segment_r) : all arguments must have the same length`.

Thoughts? I am also open to a solution that generates multiple graphs without using a `loop` - going for speed here.

Per request, sample data below:

```
df <- read.csv(text="R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, R7, segment_r
Apples, Fruit salad, Pasta, Mexican, Apples, Cheese, Salad, Segment 1
Apples, Fruit salad, Pasta, Mexican, Apples, Cheese, Salad, Segment 1
Oranges, Fruit salad, Pasta, Mexican, Oranges, Cheese, Salad, Segment 1
Oranges, Fruit salad, Pasta, Mexican, Oranges, Cheese, Salad, Segment 1
Oranges, Fruit salad, Pasta, Thai, Oranges, Cheese, Salad, Segment 1
Oranges, Fruit salad, Pasta, Thai, Oranges, Cheese, Salad, Segment 1
Oranges, Fruit salad, Pasta, Thai, Oranges, Cheese, Salad, Segment 2
Oranges, Ice cream, Pasta, Thai, Oranges, Milk, Salad, Segment 2
Bananas, Ice cream, Pasta, Thai, Bananas, Milk, Salad, Segment 2
Bananas, Ice cream, Pasta, Chinese, Bananas, Milk, Salad, Segment 2
Bananas, Ice cream, Pasta, Chinese, Bananas, Milk, Salad, Segment 2
Bananas, Pie, Pasta, Chinese, Bananas, Milk, Side, Segment 2
Bananas, Pie, Pasta, Chinese, Bananas, Milk, Side, Segment 2
Bananas, Pie, Pizza, Chinese, Bananas, Milk, Side, Segment 3
Bananas, Pie, Pizza, Chinese, Bananas, Milk, Side, Segment 3
Apples, Fruit salad, Pasta, Mexican, Apples, Milk, Side, Segment 4
Apples, Fruit salad, Pasta, Mexican, Apples, Milk, Side, Segment 4
Oranges, Fruit salad, Pasta, Mexican, Oranges, Milk, Side, Segment 4
Oranges, Fruit salad, Pasta, Mexican, Oranges, None, Side, Segment 4
Oranges, Fruit salad, Pasta, Thai, Oranges, None, Side, Segment 1
Oranges, Fruit salad, Pasta, Thai, Oranges, None, Side, Segment 1
Oranges, Fruit salad ,Pasta, Thai, Oranges, None, Side, Segment 2
Oranges, Ice cream, Pasta, Thai, Oranges, None, Side, Segment 2
Bananas, Ice cream, Pasta, Thai, Bananas, None, Side, Segment 2
Bananas, Ice cream, Pasta, Chinese, Bananas, None, Fries, Segment 2
Bananas, Ice cream, Pasta, Chinese, Bananas, None, Fries, Segment 2
Bananas, Pie, Pasta, Chinese, Bananas, None, Fries, Segment 2
Bananas, Pie, Pasta, Chinese, Bananas, None, Fries, Segment 2
Bananas, Pie, Pizza, Chinese, Bananas, None, Fries, Segment 3
Bananas, Pie, Pizza, Chinese, Bananas, None, Fries, Segment 3")
```

Comment: Thoughts: 1. Don't use `attach`. 2. Don't use `get`. 3. I can't help you with alternatives unless you share a little bit of sample data. Are the R1:7 variables separate, or columns of `df`? What are the columns? You probably don't mean `for(i in length(...))` but rather `for(i in 1:length(...))`, but the for loop doesn't actually seem necessary at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear to me what exactly you want to "do" with these plots. But translating your code into something that "works" might look like this

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

question_names <- paste("R", 1:7, sep='') # Create list with question names

for (q in question_names) {
  means <- prop.table(table(df[[q]], df[["segment_r"]]),2)*100
  means.long <- melt(means, id.vars="segment_r")
  p <- ggplot(means.long, aes(x=Var1, y=value, fill=factor(Var2)))+
    geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge") + coord_flip()+
    scale_fill_discrete(name="Segment",
                        breaks=c(1:4),
                        labels=c(1:4))+
    xlab("")+ylab("Mean Percentage")
  p <- p + facet_wrap( ~ Var2, ncol=4)
  print(p)
}
```

This will would put all the plots to the graphics window (though the last plot overwrites the previous plot). But this gets rid of `attach()` and `get()` at least.

Comment: Just taking screenshot from RStudio to add to a presentation :) This works!

Comment: OK, well I would just note that I don't consider this code to use "modern" R techniques. Rather than looping it would be easier to use a `purrr::map` and rather than `prop.table/melt` you could create the summary use `dplyr`. I just did the minimal amount to get it running.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations! I will share with my team.